# When is: 'X paracompact iff X has $\sigma$-locally finite refinement' true?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading my course notes about paracompact spaces and there is the following result:

> $X$ is paracompact iff every open cover of $X$ has a $\sigma$-locally
>   finite open refinement.

However the proof uses the following result from a problem sheet we did:

> For a regular space, the following are equivalent,
>
> 1. X is paracompact
> 2. Every open cover of $X$ has a locally finite refinement
> 3. Every open cover of $X$ has a locally finite closed refinement

However the original theorem in the notes does not include any seperation assumption. So is the first result only valid for regular spaces?

**EDIT**

Looking at Willards 'General Topology', theorem 20.12 says

> Every $F_\sigma$ subset of a paracompact space is paracompact.

The proof of this result shows that every open cover of a $F_\sigma$ subset has a $\sigma$-locally finite refinement.

Hence is the implication

> $X$  has a $\sigma$-locally finite open refinement $\implies X$ is
>   paracompact

true without the regularity property, but the converse needs the regularity?

Comment: For the last statement the converse is trivial, as a locally finite open refinement is certainly a $\sigma$-locally finite one. So it could only be the forward direction that needs regularity.

Comment: Maybe your text assumes all spaces are at least Hausdorff in this context? Engelking does so, e.g.

Comment: See my answer: in summary: the first and last statements need regularity. The $F_\sigma$ fact holds for Willard's definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use regularity in the proof of $2 \implies 3$ of from your equivalence (from the problem sheet), but not in the other steps. See [my note on this here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/03.pdf), if you want to check my proof. It's 3 to 4 there as I add another equivalence with "every open cover has a $\sigma$-locally finite open refinement" in that lemma; so we have it all in one go, so the formulation I chose was the equivalence (for regular spaces) of

1. $X$ paracompact (every open cover has a locally finite open refinement).
2. Every open cover has a $\sigma$-locally finite open refinement.
3. Every open cover has a locally finite refinement (i.e. a cover but not necessarily open).
4. Every open cover has a locally finite closed refinement.

- $1 \implies 2$ is trivial and needs nothing, just like $1 \implies 3$.
- $2 \implies 3$ needs no regularity in the proof I gave.
- For $3 \implies 4$, I do use the regularity.
- $4 \implies 1$ also doesn't use it.

Your first result you state is the equivalence of 1 and 2 and I see no path here from 2 to 1 that avoids 3 to 4 somehow... So regularity seems needed.

An example: if $X$ is a Lindelöf Hausdorff, non-regular space, then $X$ obeys the property that every open cover has a $\sigma$-locally finite open refinement (a countable subcover will do that easily) but such an $X$ is not paracompact as a paracompact Hausdorff space is both regular and normal, as is well-known.
Such spaces have been found in abundance (see [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Hausdorff%20%2B%20%7E%20%24T_3%24%20%2B%20Lindelof) e.g., the Arens square and the irational slope topology are the most "famous")

The $F_\sigma$ subset result will hold because Willard (as Engelking) defines a paracompact space to be Hausdorff, and such a space is thus normal and regular, and so the $F_\sigma$ subspace is regular too and the lemma applies to it.